# Msg 3902, Level 16, State 1. The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @cnt_inv int,
        @cnt_jrn int, 
        @pl_per varchar(2), 
        @pl_yr  varchar(4), 
        @pl_jrn varchar (6), 
        @pl_inv varchar (6)

IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION JD_Imp


            IF @cnt_inv > 0 
            BEGIN
            BEGIN TRANSACTION JD_Inv



        COMMIT TRANSACTION JD_Inv; 
                    PRINT N'The Invoice Commits DONE.';
        END

            IF @cnt_jrn > 0 
            BEGIN
            BEGIN TRANSACTION JD_Jrn


        COMMIT TRANSACTION JD_Jrn;  
                    PRINT N'The Journals Commits DONE.';
        END
COMMIT TRANSACTION JD_Imp;
END
```

Answer (score 2):

The core of your issue is this:

```
IF @cnt_jrn > 0 
        BEGIN TRANSACTION JD_Jrn
```

All this will do is only start a new transaction if `@cnt_jrn > 0`. It's still going to execute all of the code below regardless of the condition. So if `@cnt_jrn <= 0`, it's going to call `commit transaction JD_Jrn` without ever having started it.

You need to enclose the body of *any* multi-statement `if` body with `begin` and `end`. For example:

```
IF @cnt_jrn > 0 
BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION JD_Jrn

        ... code ...
END
```

But you are enclosing single `insert` and `update` statements in transactions, which is not necessary. SQL operations are guaranteed to be atomic, so you only need a transaction if you're spanning multiple operations.

Comment: 1. I have enclosed the body of the if body with the BEGIN and END.  When I do this, the procedure runs and has the error message Command(s) completed successfully.
2. When I look at my tables, there is no new records. That means I have only removed the error message but not solved the under-lying problem. No inserts.

Comment: "Command(s) completed successfully" is not an error message. If you're not seeing inserts, then either a) you have uncommitted transactions at the end of the batch, b) your logic (either intrinsically or as expressed in the code) is wrong, or c) your values are not as expected. It's impossible to tell which is the probable cause without seeing your (now updated) code and a printout of the variable values.

Comment: I have made the changes as advised by Adam. I'm failing to repost the modified script. not enough space

Comment: @hcaneshcanes: Edit your question to include the new code; you won't be able to post it in a comment.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I have put the new code using the edit option. When the procedure is run no inserts occur. When I try to run the debug, the debug does not move from the first. When I drag the debug arrow for me to run through the code I get the message "Unable to use the next statement to this location. There is no executablecode at this location in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.....

(a) Having the Begin...END Blocks did solve the error message Msg 3902.. I noticed that without the BEGIN..END Blocks, previous runs of the procedure will still be hanging uncommitted

(b) IF @@ERROR <> 0 BEGIN will always be true so no wonder the script block inside was not being executed.

(c) The Debugger was not moving past the IF statement due to (b).

Thanks a lot Adam.

Comment: If my answer led you to a solution, please be sure to accept it by clicking on the checkmark. You may also want to revert your question so that the original code is there for others in the future.